# Please help me to prove the convergence of $\gamma_{n} = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+....+\frac{1}{n}-\ln n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, euler-mascheroni-constant

Please help me to prove tha
 $$\gamma_{n} = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+....+\frac{1}{n}-\ln n$$ converges and its limit is $\gamma \in [0,1]$. Then, using  $\gamma_{n}$ find the sum: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I'd suggest though you'd ask question in a less imperative way and in a more friendly way. Plus, have you managed to find something? Any approaches? What I mean is, you're not a book, you're human, so act like one, it makes us more willing to answer. =)

Comment: The following [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55358/asymptotic-behavior-of-left-sum-limits-j-1n-frac1j-right-logn/55372#55372) addresses the convergence

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42367/what-is-lim-n-to-infty-sum-k-1n-1-k)

Comment: Sorry because my question was imperative. My english is not very good and I translated word by word from my language. I will be more carefully next time.

Comment: In the sense that if you read the answer given, all the good stuff's in there. Although they don't compute the alternated sum. I don't agree it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55358/asymptotic-behavior-of-left-sum-limits-j-1n-frac1j-right-logn/55372#55372) addresses the convergence, so assume $\gamma_n$ converges and denote the limit as $\gamma$.

Now consider  $\sum_{n=1}^{2m} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{n}$ and split it into even and odd terms
$\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{2n-1} - \sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{2n}$. Then complete the sum over odd integers to sum over consequtive integers: $\sum_{n=1}^{2m} \frac{1}{n} - 2 \sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{2n}$.

Then subtract logarithms to form $\gamma_{2m} - 2 \gamma_m + \log(2)$, like so 
$$ ( \sum_{n=1}^{2m} \frac{1}{n} - \log(2m)) - ( \sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{n} - \log(m)) + \log(2).$$

In the limit $m \to \infty$ it becomes $ \gamma - \gamma + \log(2) = \log(2)$.

Comment: Thank you for your help too!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the mean value theorem to prove first that
$$\frac{1}{n+1}<\ln(n+1)-\ln n<\frac{1}{n}$$
then, $\ln(n+1)<1+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}<1+\ln n$, and finally
$$\ln(n+1)-\ln n<\gamma_n<1$$
which implies the convergence of $\gamma_n$ and its limit $\gamma\in[0,1]$.

For the second part, I am not sure if you can use $\gamma_n$ to find the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n}$!

I suggest to use the Taylor-Young formula for $x\mapsto\ln(x+1)$ on $[0,1]$ to prove that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n}=\ln2.$$

Comment: Thank you !I learnt mean value theorem in highschool but I completely forgot about it.

Comment: @amine it's mercator series time...

Answer (score 2):

The Mean Value Theorem says
$$
\frac{1}{k+1}<\log(k+1)-\log(k)<\frac{1}{k}
$$
Summing from $m$ to $n-1$ ($m < n$), we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k+1}<\log(n)-\log(m)<\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}
\end{align}
$$
Subtracting $\displaystyle{\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k+1}=\sum_{k=m+1}^n\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{k}}$ from all parts, we get
$$
0<\left(\log(n)-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\right)-\left(\log(m)-\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{k}\right)<\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{n}
$$
This proves the existence of $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\log(n)-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\right)}$. If we set $m=1$ and subtract all sides from $1$, we get
$$
1>\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}-\log(n)\right)>\frac{1}{n}
$$Thus, we have shown that $\displaystyle{\gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}-\log(n)\right)}$ exists, and that $0\le\gamma\le 1$.

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{k}&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}-2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\\
&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}-\log(2n)\right)-\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}-\log(n)\right)+\log(2)
\end{align}
$$
Taking the limit as $n\to\infty$, we get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{k}=\gamma-\gamma+\log(2)=\log(2)
$$

Comment: I apologize if this is close to Sasha's answer, but I have been working on this, during breaks, for quite a while, and posted it before I noticed.  Since I show more of the details, I will leave it for now.  I can remove it if requested.

Comment: Sorry, for the convergence, I forgot to say that $\gamma_n$ is decreasing because $$\gamma_{n+1}-\gamma_n=\frac{1}{n+1}-(\ln(n+1)-\ln n)<0$$ since it is bounded, it is convergent!

Answer (score 1):

Do we have a "proof without words" question here?  I don't find it.  There is a lovely diagram found in certain calculus texts that does this for us.  Maybe I will animate it, for fun.

Comment: I am not getting this. Do you mean pictorial proof, which suggests the proof ?

Comment: It's something like the diagram at the top right here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant  but then you slide all the blue regions to the left to see that they all fit inside a $1 \times 1$ square.